How to enable Drag and Drop in Vue/JS/HTML with an inventory system?
I want to recreate a inventory system like the one in minecraft as it is helping understand a lot of web dev stuff and just overall becoming a better developer, my code is not working and updating my elements in the grid as it should.
GridBlock.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, type Ref } from 'vue'

//const props = defineProps(['item'])

const selected: Ref<HTMLElement | null> = ref(null)

const randomColor = () => {
  //#1f3f5f
  return `#${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)}f${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)}f${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)}f`
}

const handleClick = (e: Event) => {
  let target = e.target as HTMLElement
  target.style.backgroundColor = randomColor()
}

const handleDragStart = (e: DragEvent) => {
  let target = e.target as HTMLElement
  selected.value = target
}

const handleDragOver = (e: DragEvent) => {
  e.preventDefault()
}

const handleDrop = (e: DragEvent) => {
  e.preventDefault()

  let target = e.currentTarget as HTMLElement

  if (selected.value && selected.value !== target) {
    const temp = target.innerHTML
    target.innerHTML = selected.value.innerHTML
    selected.value.innerHTML = temp
    selected.value = null
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div
    class="grid-block"
    draggable="true"
    @click="handleClick"
    @dragstart="handleDragStart"
    @dragover="handleDragOver"
    @drop="handleDrop"
  >
    <div class="item-block">
      {{ Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
.grid-block {
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: beige;
}
.item-block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
</style>


GridDisplay.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import GridBlock from './GridBlock.vue'

function range(start: number, end: number): number[] {
  return Array.from({ length: end - start + 1 }, (_, i) => start + i)
}

const blocks = range(1, 16)
</script>

<template>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <GridBlock v-for="i in blocks" :key="i" :id="i"></GridBlock>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 7.4rem);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 7.4rem);
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}
</style>


I tried asking ChatGPT if there are any flaws in my logic and I followed a tutorial on Youtube on the drag and drop feature in vanilla JS then tried implementing it inside VUE, I was expecting that when I drag a grid block on top of another grid block, the target grid block will get all the data and styling inside the selected grid block, but instead nothing happens, and I see no details or errors in my debugging tools that I can use to fix this. I am still a noobie to all this, so help will be apreeciated.

It will be good if you can create a minimal reproducible example on fiddle, or similar platform.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In handleDragStart you set selected.value = target and you do the reverse in handleDrop where selected is a global variable with the type of HTMLElement. I don't know TypeScript, but my guess would be that you should just set selected = target and then to get the element target.innerHTML = selected.innerHTML.

You never set selected to a value, and most of your logic is wrapped in if (selected.value && selected.value !== target).
You will probably want to use the dragenter and dragleave events here to figure out where your item is being dropped.
You will also receive a DataTransfer object as part of those events, which contains information you may want.
Also, check out useDraggable and useDropZone from VueUse. They do similar things, and the source code is available.
